# Ant design message doesnot work on onclick

Tags: reactjs, antd, message, ant-design-pro

So I am trying to display a message when a button is clicked but what it does is that when the page is loaded it displays message boxes (which should not happen) but it doesn't work on onclick I have attached the screenshots to my code and views.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass your function to the onClick parameter, not invoke it.

```
<Button type="primary" shape="round" onClick={() => info()} />
```

or

```
<Button type="primary" shape="round" onClick={info} />
```